# Why does spark-submit error out with "Cannot load main class from JAR" for --jars option?

Tags: apache-spark

I tried this command in pycharm terminal to connect to mysql server.

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit –-jars /Users/akay_nation/Desktop/spark/jars/mysql-connector-java-8.0.19 abc.py
```

But while running this command im getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Cannot load main class from JAR file:/Users/akay_nation/PycharmProjects/abc/–-jars
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.error(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:657)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.loadEnvironmentArguments(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:221)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.<init>(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:116)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2$$anon$1.<init>(SparkSubmit.scala:907)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.parseArguments(SparkSubmit.scala:907)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:81)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:920)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:929)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Can anyone tell me whats the issue? Or is it not the right command to connect to mysql server?

Answer (score 0):

The two characters `--` in front of the `jars` option do not really look like two dashes so you ended up with something that pretends to be `--jars`, but it's not. That's why `spark-submit` errors out with the following `SparkException`:

```
SparkException: Cannot load main class from JAR file:/Users/akay_nation/PycharmProjects/abc/–-jars
```

Comment: I tried above change but getting this error:-                                                           
 ERROR SparkContext: Failed to add file:/Users/akay_nation/Desktop/spark/jars/mysql-connector-java-8.0.19 to Spark environment

Comment: There's no `/Users/akay_nation/Desktop/spark/jars/mysql-connector-java-8.0.19` jar file? Note the missing extension.

Comment: so is there any other way to connect to  mysql server using spark submit